# The physical intuition behind some simplifications in electrochemistry

Tags: electrochemistry

> Find the standard reduction potential of
>
> $$\ce{AgIO3(s) + e- <=>  Ag(s) + IO3-}.$$
>
> $K_\mathrm{sp} = \pu{3.1E-8},$ and the standard reduction potential of $\ce{Ag +e- <=> Ag(s)}$ is $E = \pu{0.799 V}.$

So, $E^\circ$ will be standard reduction potential and $E$ will be the nonstandard.

$$
\begin{align}
E(\ce{AgIO3/Ag}) &= E^\circ(\ce{AgIO3/Ag}) - 0.0257\ln\frac{1}{[\ce{Ag}]}\\
  &= E^\circ(\ce{AgIO3/Ag}) - 0.0257\ln\frac{[\ce{IO3}]}{\pu{3.1E-8}}
\end{align}
$$

$$\pu{0.799 V} = E^\circ(\ce{AgIO3/Ag}) - 0.0257\ln\frac{1}{\pu{3.1E-8}}$$

Now, my concern is that I understand the math and like most of the principles behind all this, but how come when we set $[\ce{IO3}] = 1,$ we can also say $E (\ce{AgIO3/Ag})$ is equal to $E(\ce{Ag})?$

**tl;dr**: how come setting the concentration of the anion to $\pu{1 M}$ allows us to assume that variable change for the electrode?

Comment: I took a liberty to format your question for better readability and proper notations; if you are interested further in technical details, feel free to visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your future posts better with MathJax and Markdown.